# Extract Email Address from Nested Tables in HTML Emails

Tags: html-email

I will be receiving approx 500 emails over the next day or so. The emails are all identical in layout i.e. HTML emails that display information inside a table. There are nested tables within the email.

I need to extract the email address from each email and store it in a file (text/csv). Rather than "copy & paste", is there a php script or some browser plugin I can use to do this?

GF

Answer (score 0):

I will use php parse by id,class or name and a little script to go throw all the pages inside that folder to extract it as a csv I'll use fputcsv.

Hope it helped.